# How do I do URL re-writes on Plesk?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewriting, plesk

I am very new to URL re-writing and I am using Plesk which is **window-based** web server, hence I can't use Apache's mod_Rewrite. Can anyone tell me what is the proper procedure for this?

Comment: Plesk is a webserver _control panel_ that can run on Windows and Linux. It is not itself a webserver and is not the reason why you can't use mod_rewrite. What webserver are you using?

Comment: I am using windows based web server

Comment: The reason why you cannot use mod_rewrite is because you are not using Apache (which can run on Windows), not necessarily because you are using a "windows based web server". It seems, from comments, that you might be running **IIS**. So, the answer you are looking for needs to be targeted specifically for this webserver and version. You should really be asking something like... "What is IIS _[ENTER VERSION HERE]_ equivalent of Apache's mod_rewrite?"

Comment: @w3d Even more specifically, "how do I do rewrites in IIS using Plesk?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Plesk there is usually a server section where you can configure which Apache modules should be activated. "rewrite" or "mod_rewrite" is the one to activate.

Then it depends on your software or scripts to make actually use of this module.

[Edit]
Do you have the url rewrite extension available or can it be installed? See
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: But there is no module like this..

Comment: Oh... do you have only IIS available on windows?

Comment: yess @initall..

Comment: this was a perfect answer & its working also there is a tutorial which explains everything to you.. thanx a lot..:)

Answer (score 0):

its [isapirewrite.com](http://isapirewrite.com) we have to install this 
This s/w will work same as mod_rewrite in windows web servers

They will charge some $99 for s/w

Answer (score 0):

You can import the .htaccess rules on Windows hosting without any problems. If you have access to to IIS manager, just enter it, go to your domain and open the section Url-rewrite rules.Then use the Import button and your rules will be automatically imported to your web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

- https://gist.github.com/sabbour/e49b3ac9e1438c93d5fb

Just create a web.config file on Notepad or edit the one you have on the root folder of Magento, and copy and paste this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
  <configuration> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <rewrite> 
      <rules> 
        <rule name="Remove index.php rule" stopProcessing="true"> 
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false"/> 
          <conditions> 
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/(media|skin|js)/" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" /> 
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
          </conditions> 
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" /> 
        </rule> 
      </rules> 
    </rewrite> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```